# Running certain procedure in event fails

Tags: mysql, events, stored-procedures

I want to call procedure at certain time, so I instatinate an event that will do it (call procedure) for me. Code looks like this:

```
CALL MainProcedure(@firstOutParam, @secondOutParam);

SELECT @moveId, @endTime; #select just for check if parameters are ok

CREATE EVENT myevent1 ON SCHEDULE AT @endTime DO CALL 
`database`.`SupportingProcedure`(@firstOutParam);

CREATE EVENT myevent2 ON SCHEDULE AT @endTime DO CALL `database`.`OnlyForTestProcedure`();
```

Both `SupportingProcedure` and `OnlyForTestProcedure` when called not from event work properly, also, myevent2 calls .`OnlyForTestProcedure`.

The only thing that doesn't work is myevent1. It appears on `show events`, it then disappears but it doesn't work (`SupportingProcedure` either isn't called or doesn't work..).

Do you see anything I do wrong? What should I do to make it work?
Any help appreciated, I have no clue what else to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned earlier `CREATE EVENT` within procedure is not possible, it probably shuts the topic, but read on.

1) If you use MySQL with PHP and need single event in database, you can instantinate one via mysqli query method.

2) If you need to keep track of certain changes in tables you may can create an event that is some sort of daemon. Just set it to:

`CREATE EVENT EventDaemon
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 SECOND STARTS NOW() DO 
   CALL procedure();`

where `procedure` executes its body only if specific requirements occurs (that would make you CREATE EVENT in original situation). Can't really tell if it's efficient, but it works fine for me.

I hope I've made myself clear.

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled the event scheduler ?

You need an entry in `my.cnf` under the `[mysqld]` section saying:

```
event_scheduler=on
```

If the event somehow fails, mysql has poor support for diagnosing it, but you'll see some log entries in the mysql log file (which is usually located in the mysql data directory, e.g. /var/lib/mysql or under the system logs /var/log)

The documentation statest there's no way to pass an argument to and from a procedure invoked by an event, so your first event that pass in `@firstOutParam` will probably not work. To get around that you'll have to build the SQL dynamically as text and execute it.

```
SET @sql = CONCAT("CREATE EVENT myevent1 ON SCHEDULE AT ", @endTime, " DO CALL 
`database`.`SupportingProcedure`(",@firstOutParam,")");
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: Event scheduler is on, but I've checked and you're right; passing parameters into procedure in event doesn't work. Your idea is ok, but according to [MySQL Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html) "The following SQL statements can be used in prepared statements: `ALTER TABLE, CALL, COMMIT, CREATE INDEX, CREATE TABLE, DELETE, DO, DROP INDEX, DROP TABLE, INSERT, RENAME TABLE, REPLACE, SELECT, SET, UPDATE, and most SHOW statements`." Seems to be a deadlock to me..

Comment: Since it was MySQL problem I haven't mentioned that it's used with PHP. I query for output params, retrieve values and then query database back with concatenated query string. It's far from elegance, but it works, so it'll stay. @nos, you helped me a lot, but I only have 6 reputation points, so maybe I'll do it later. Question is open until I find someting better.